# GIS data on Lewis & Clark expedition?

Tags: united-states

I'm looking for historians' best estimate of the location of the Lewis & Clark expedition at each date during the trip, in a machine-readable format (e.g. that I could use in a GIS system).

(Since the party split up at various points, ideally I'd get the locations of each group on each date.)

After a bit of searching, I'm surprised not to have found anything like this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for references.

Comment: You have found no map of the Lewis and Clark Expedition.  Seriously?

Comment: There are plenty of maps. I want to be able to download the data in a machine-readable format to make my own maps.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for something similar and found this:

http://www.uen.org/Lessonplan/preview.cgi?LPid=9877

It has some shape files for the route they took, major mountain passes, and significant sites.

Answer (score 0):

The National Park Service has created a polyline shapefile that plots Lewis and Clark's historic route as closely as possible, based on the work of a few historians as well as models of historic river channels.

You can view the route [in an interactive NPS.gov webmap](https://imgis.nps.gov/HTML/index.html?viewer=LECL) alongside the data sources used to create it, plus conduct basic analyses such as measuring distances. To use the data in your own desktop GIS, the shapefile is [downloadable from ArcGIS Online](https://hub.arcgis.com/items/8a5d4ac482ee4b24baca6dbab5422dbc) with a free ArcGIS Online account.